# Get return of a function without sending anything

Tags: c++

I have a function header:

```
double countThis(double counter);
```

Then, in my main I do this:

```
double test = 10;
countThis(test);
```

Then comes the function:

```
double countThis(double counter) {
    double counted = counter;
    return counted;
}
```

On the bottom, I have one last function, and here I want to get `double counted` without having to do `countThis(something)`, I just want to get the return from the previous call that was made in main and get the value 10 (counted).

Comment: You cannot access a local variable from outside the function. Or did I misunderstood what you want to do?

Comment: Store the result of `countThis` in a local variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this sort of persistence is to use a class and define an *instance* of that class:

```
struct Counter
{
    double counted;
    double countThis(double counter)
    {
        return counted = counter; // assign counter to counted, and return that value.
    }
};
```

At the point of use:

```
int main()
{
    Counter c;
    c.countThis(10);
    // c.counted contains the last value sent to countThis, in this case, 10
}
```

The *instance* `c` is used to *persist* the value that you pass to `countThis`.

Comment: It works to print c.counted in main. But when I do Counter cc in another function and then print cc.counted it gives me the error: uninitialized local variable 'cc' used. Why is that?

Comment: You could set a default value for `counted` by writing a *constructor* in `Counter`.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
double test = 10;
double ret;
ret = countThis(test);
// Now the value returned by countThis is in ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variable.(double counted) and in the function

```
double countThis(double counter) {
   counted = counter;
    return counted;
}
```

define another function to just return counted

```
double count() {
    return counted;
}
```

But,i suggest you to create a struct and make getter and setter on it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy the value into a new instance of `double`?

Example:

```
double test = 10;
countThis(test);

double something = test;
```